# Java- && Evaluation

Tags: java

Can anybody help me on following issue:

I have code like:

```
if(cond1 && cond2 && .. && cond10)
```

Here, cond1 are expensive operations whose output is Boolean.

Now my question is what JAVAC will do, when cond2 output is false. Specifically, is it goes evaluate cond3 's output or stops evaluation ?

More illustratively,

```
if(cond1 && cond2 && .. && cond10)
  //do this
```

and

```
if(cond1){
  if(cond2){
         .
         .
         .
        if(cond10){
             //do this
                   }
```

are same in java (in case of execution way) ?

Comment: both are same ...first snippets evaluate as you see in second....

Comment: It will stop when it hits false. Also you should probably put the least expensive conditions first, because if any one of the conditions fails, the whole thing fails. Why check expensive conditions if you don't have to??

Comment: @PaulG, that's why I asked, Is it evaluated in LR way or RL way ?

Comment: LR, not RL. So least expensive on the left. Edit: I put all this is an answer below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `&&` operator always short-circuits on `false`. Condition 3 will only be evaluated if conditions 1 and 2 are `true`.

Answer (score 6):

If the entire expression is `&&` or `||` then Java will use short-circuit evaluation. That means if everything is `&&` it will stop after the first false and if everything is `||` it will stop after the first true.

Comment: Thanks. Is it evaluated in LR way or RL way ?

Comment: if you mean Left to Right or Right to Left, then it's evaluated Left to Right.

Comment: It has nothing to to with the 'entire expression'. Those operators are evaluated short-circuit *individually.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes your code snippets are equivalent. The logic AND operator is in Java short-circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Java will exit that check as soon as it finds out that one of the values is false.

Likewise, it'll do what you expect with OR as soon as it finds out that one of the values is true.

No need to evaluate the others.

Answer (score 2):

It will stop as soon as it hits a false (this is known as short circuit logic). In your case cond3 will never be evaluated. Also, the conditions are evaluated from left to right, so it's always a good idea to put the least expensive conditions on the left. This will avoid unnecessarily evaluating an expensive condition.

Example (pseudo code)

```
if(JohnIsMale && IsJohnsCholesterolTooHigh())
   {
   //Tell John to take it easy on the ice cream cause he could develop a heart condition
   }
```

Don't check the second condition first as it requires calculcation. If he is not male (a simple true or false) you'll never have to check the second.

Answer (score 1):

To answer directly:   Yes, they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

it work like....

```
if(cond1){ //if its true then check con2 ,else exit
  if(cond2){//if its true then check con 3, else exit
       if(cond3){.....


and Both code snippets  are same
```

Answer (score 1):

&&  will be executed Left to right if any single condition false the condition will be break and Whole condition will be false. Suppose cond2 is false then cond3.. and others will not executed. In other hands 
If you use single & it will executed from left to right until all conditions processed doesn't matter false or true. Thats the difference && will stop the exection on first false and & will continue till the last condition.